# Gatsby cara theme build is giving blanck screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, github-pages, static-site

I have cloned a Gatsby theme and changed it slightly with my name

https://github.com/LekoArts/gatsby-themes/tree/master/themes/gatsby-theme-cara

Everything works fine with

```
gatsby develop
```

and

```
gatsby build
```

But the static site (inside public folder) is blank when opened up in browser!!!

Is am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No i didn't touch any configuration at all... Ne just pull the repository then executed develop and build command with slight string change for my name in intro.mdx.